# How to use Meteor and D3 to draw circles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor

I have a set of data inside a Meteor.Collection with x and y values. All I want is to take these and draw them onto the screen as circles using these x/y positions. However, I can't find a way to do this. Is there anyone willing to help me with some lines of code? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your d3 rendering logic in the template's `rendered` callback, assuming that the template is an isolated piece of d3 drawing. Inside the `rendered` callback start a reactive computation with `Deps.autorun` and put your d3 drawing code inside. Don't forget to stop the reactive computation when the template is no longer rendered.

Look at the standard parties example that accomplishes it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/parties/client/client.js#L130